# Change session variable and reload page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC for some database queries and have a session variable that selects which part of the database the queries should use. Now I want to have a dropdown menu on each page that allows changing the session variable. After changing it, the current page should be reloaded and use the new value.

Now I could implement this for each action on my controllers, but I would prefer a more general approach. My idea was to change the session variable and then reload the page the user was on when he clicked the option in the dropdown menu.

How do you implement something like this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `HttpRequest.UrlReferer` property. Create the single action in some controller:

```
public class SomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Change(int value)
    {
        Session["Value"] = value;
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case is processing parameter in `OnActioniExecuting` method and setting session parameter value.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        if( Request.RequestType == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Request.Form.Get( "sessionParameter" ) ) )
        {
            Session["sessionParameter"] = Request.Form.Get("sessionParameter");
        }
        //set parameter and process it later as you want 
        ViewBag.SessionParameter = Session["sessionParameter"];
    }
}
```

HTML sample:

```
Current value: @ViewBag.SessionParameter

<form action="/" method="post">
    <select name="sessionParameter" id="ddl">
        <option value="1" @(ViewBag.SessionParameter == "1" ? "selected" : "")>1</option>
        <option value="2" @(ViewBag.SessionParameter == "2" ? "selected" : "")>2</option>
        <option value="3" @(ViewBag.SessionParameter == "3" ? "selected" : "")>3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');
    ddl.onchange = function() {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    };
</script>
```